# Scrape and Get main content of any web site

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape web page an get title and main content of any web site. i see [this](http://www.textteaser.com/). if you copy any url (for example copy `http://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/pakistani-army-fuels-anger-securing-swat-taliban-025337458.html` to textbox and press enter) from any article this web page get title and article and summarize it. it's work for the most websites. i want to know how is work without using html tag parsing for any website? how get main article of each webpage?

Comment: That project *is* open source, so why don't you just look at [the source code](https://github.com/MojoJolo/textteaser)?

Comment: nice! @Blender i think fetcher source code isn't here.